# Laravel 5 pivot table project<->user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot

I find the pivot tables pretty complicated and I don't see what to do next or what I am doing wrong, I've found some tutorials but didn't help me in my needs.

I have a `projects` and `users` with a `many-to-many` relation.
One `project hasMany users` and One `user hasMany projects`.

What I have now leaves projects without a relationship to a user.

This is what I have so far:

**Projects table**

```
class CreateProjectsTable extends Migration {

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('projects', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->date('completion_date');
        $table->integer('completed')->default(0);
        $table->integer('active')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Users table**

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('company_id');
        $table->integer('project_id');
        $table->integer('usertype_id')->default(0);
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
    });
}
```

**Project User table (pivot)**

```
class CreateProjectUsersTable extends Migration {

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('project_users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('project_id')->references('id')->on('project');;
        $table->integer('user_id')->references('id')->on('user');;
    });
}
```

**User model**

```
public function projects() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project', 'project_users', 'user_id', 'project_id');
}
```

**Project model**

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'project_users', 'project_id', 'user_id');
}
```

**Project controller**

```
public function index(Project $project)
{

   $projects = $project->with('users')->get();

    dd($projects);

    $currenttime = Carbon::now();

    //return view('project.index', array('projects' => $projects, 'currenttime' => $currenttime));

    return view('user.index', compact('projects'));
}
```

Comment: Just curious: Why do 'project_users' table has it's own incremental ID?

Comment: In my head I figured it out the pivot table would be something like: (project_users_id = 1, project_id = 5,  user_id = 8) (for example) Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I realised that but is this possible:

id 1, project_id: 2, user_id: 3 | id 2, project_id: 2, user_id: 3 ? Twice the same values (same user related to the same project twice)

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish with the pivot table.  If you don't want duplicates (the same user owning the same project twice), then it's better to have a composite primary key of `project_id` and `user_id` to keep duplicates from happening on the database level and not have the `id` because it becomes unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship in your `User` model is not correct.  You have to swap the keys.

```
public function projects() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project', 'project_users', 'user_id', 'project_id');
}
```

**Edit regarding latest comment:**

Don't think about the pivot table, as long as you have your relations setup correctly, which I believe they are, Laravel handles all of that for you.

Now `$projects->users` does not make any sense because `projects` does not have `users`.  `projects` is just a collection of `Project`.  Each `Project` within that collection will have a `users` relation.  You would have to iterate through the collection to view each `Project`'s  users.

```
foreach($projects as $project) {
    foreach($project->users as $user) {
        echo $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured that out already, but it still does return me empty relationships. As for know what I have it should return (when the database is filled) with dd($projects) a relationship in the project right?

Comment: It should, instead of `dd($projects);` try `dd($projects->toArray());`  The relationship attributes may be nested too deeply in the collection for them to show when dumped.

Comment: 0 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => "1"
    "name" => "project"
    "users" => [] still returning an empty users value whilst this project actually has a user (user with this project_id)

Comment: That's strange.  I'm going to set this up locally and see what happens.

Comment: It seems to work now, probably a typo somewhere, thanks alot for your help.

Comment: On the other way around, when I do dd($projects->users)) it will give a `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::users()` while it should give something in return.. Please help! I'm so stuck with the pivots

Comment: I've modified my answer a bit to explain more clearly what may be happening.